# How to use DataTrigger from code in Silverlight?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, datatrigger

I have found a few examples that relate to WPF, but none for Silverlight.

So, what is a working example of setting up a [`Microsoft.Expression.Interactivity.Core.DataTrigger`](http://expression.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.expression.interactivity.core.datatrigger%28Expression.40%29.aspx) in code?

Here is the code I currently have, though it doesn't work (no exceptions, but nothing happens at runtime):

```
// Set up a storyboard
var duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(400));
var animation = new ColorAnimation
{
    To = Colors.White,
    RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever,
    AutoReverse = true,
    Duration = duration
};
var sb = new Storyboard
{
    RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever, 
    AutoReverse = true, 
    Duration = duration
};
sb.Children.Add(animation);
Storyboard.SetTarget(animation, fillBrush);
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, new PropertyPath("(SolidColorBrush.Color)"));

// Configure the data trigger
var focusTrigger = new DataTrigger
{
    Binding = new Binding("IsFocussed")
    {
        Source = asset,
        Mode = BindingMode.OneWay
    }, 
    Value = true
};
focusTrigger.Actions.Add(new ControlStoryboardAction
{
    Storyboard = sb, 
    ControlStoryboardOption = ControlStoryboardOption.Play, 
    IsEnabled = true
});
```

`asset.IsFocussed` changes and raises change notifications via `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Comment: Look into the debug output, looks like you have incorrect binding here: 'IsFocussed'. Maybe double "s" is a problem here?

Comment: @invisible -- thanks, but that's not the case this time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I was missing two bits:

1. Add the trigger to the brush:

   ```
   var triggers = Interaction.GetTriggers(fillBrush);
   triggers.Add(focusTrigger);
   ```
2. Set the binding on the trigger using `BindingOperators.SetBinding`, not the `Binding` property setter:

   ```
   var binding = new Binding("IsFocussed") { Source = asset, Mode = BindingMode.OneWay };
   BindingOperations.SetBinding(focusTrigger, PropertyChangedTrigger.BindingProperty, binding);
   ```

I can't quite see why the second point was necessary, but it seemed to be.

Hope that helps someone else out.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the namespace:

```
System.Windows.Interactivity
```

and add the following after your "Configure the data trigger" comment

```
// Configure the data trigger

// Configure the TriggerCollection
TriggerCollection triggers = Interaction.GetTriggers(fillBrush);
var focussedTrigger = new EventTrigger("GotFocus");
focussedTrigger.Actions.Add(
            new ControlStoryboardAction{Storyboard = sbFocussed});

var unfocussedTrigger = new EventTrigger("LostFocus");
unfocussedTrigger.Actions.Add(
            new ControlStoryboardAction { Storyboard = sbUnfocussed });

triggers.Add(focussedTrigger);
triggers.Add(unfocussedTrigger);
```

note:

```
using EventTrigger = System.Windows.Interactivity.EventTrigger;
using TriggerCollection = System.Windows.Interactivity.TriggerCollection;
```